# cloud9 node.js addon debugging

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide

I'm working on a node.js module which uses native C++ addons. I plan to move my development from vim+nemiver+node-inspector to something more integrated. For that c9 seems to do the job.

Is it possible to debug both javascript (with v8) and C++ (with gdb) at the same time?

My old setup supports this by using nemiver and node-inspector side by side, but it isn't a very pleasent workflow.

Comment: I think you can with the workspace that are docker based. You can install almost everything, give it a try.

Comment: I made some effort on this: It's now possible to debug either with gdb or with v8. But I can't get them run both on one instance